# Is CircuitLab simulator and KiCad simulator similar?

Tags: circuit-design, simulation, embedded

I have been looking for an open source circuit simulator to embed. I found one that is CircuitLab but it doesn't seem to be open source. I found an alternative called KiCad, but I am not sure if it has similar functionalities to CircuitLab. Can anyone let me know are they similar or one of them has more functions or limitations? Thank you in advance ^_^

I Google searched the similarities. Check a site (https://www.saashub.com/compare-kicad-vs-circuitlab) comparing simulators. I was expecting to see that they are similar but the website said KiCad lacks in embedded software. My apologies as I am still new to this.

Comment: Kicad's simulator is (based on) [ngspice](https://ngspice.sourceforge.io/)

Comment: Ahh I see I see. So it has the capabilities of circuitLab and more? I heard of NGSpice but never tried it yet

Comment: What are you embedding into? A web page? A binary application? Python?

Comment: A JavaScript web page. It is mainly for students to use to submit their circuits so that we can check if their submission is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for an open source circuit simulator to embed in a web page. If this is your question, please have a look at  https://github.com/sharpie7/circuitjs1

Quoting from that page:

CircuitJS1 is an electronic circuit simulator that runs in the browser. It was originally written by Paul Falstad as a Java Applet. It was adapted by Iain Sharp to run in the browser using GWT.

For a hosted version of the application see:

Paul's Page: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Iain's Page: http://lushprojects.com/circuitjs/